# How to calculate value of the recursive function?

Tags: java, recursion, asymptotic-complexity

I have the recursive function: T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n. I want to find the complexity of the function by passing different arguments to the function and getting values of the function. Then I will guess the formula of the function(e.g n, n*log(n)).

I write the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(findValueOfTheFunction(2));
    System.out.println(findValueOfTheFunction(4));
    System.out.println(findValueOfTheFunction(8));
}

static double findValueOfTheFunction(double n) {
    if(n > eps) {
        return 2*findValueOfTheFunction(n/2) + n;
    }
    else return 0;
}}
```

I get three points from the code. p1(2, 10) and p2(4, 24) and p3(8, 56).

As a understand, the complexity of the recursive function is O(n) = n*log(n). But my points doesn't fit to the formula.

I've done some research here, but nobody seems to have similar issue.

Comment: What do you mean by `O(n) = n*log(n)`? Big oh notation isn't a formula, it's an upper bound

Comment: The complexity of an algorithm has nothing to do with the output. It's about how much time it takes to get the output.

Comment: The task sounds as: "The recursive function T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n describes some algorithm. Find the complexity of the algorithm by finding values of the function for different n and then guess the formula".

Comment: That makes much more sense. So `T` is supposed to model the complexity of some other algorithm, and you are supposed to give an `O` that simulates the output of `T`.

Comment: @4castle Big O is **not** about how much time it takes to get the output!  It's about how the time required scales with the problem size.  An O(n) algorithm might take a billionth of a second or a billion seconds to solve a problem of a particular size, but it will asymptotically take twice as long to solve a problem twice that size (for sizes above some threshold).

Comment: @pjs Yes, I understand that. Big O doesn't *give* the time it takes to get the output, but it *describes* the time it takes to get the output. Therefore, it is "about how much time it takes to get the output".

Comment: @4castle Again, that's not correct.  It's about how the time *scales* with n.

Comment: @pjs I agree with you. You're just being much more specific. I'm saying "Big O is about time" and you're saying "Big O is about time with this added context". The context doesn't change the fact that it's still "about time".

Comment: @4castle You say you agree, but repeat the same incorrect interpretation.  Big-O is not about time.  It's about how resources such as time ***scale*** with the problem size.  The distinction is not about "context", it's about using terminology precisely and correctly.  Please go back and re-read your algorithms books, or the first sentence of paragraph 2 of the [Wikipedia page on Big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), or the intro paragraph of [this paper](http://www.austinmohr.com/Work_files/complexity.pdf).  These aren't matters of opinion, they're fundamental concepts.

Comment: @pjs Let me use different wording, because I'm not trying to give the definition when I say it's "about time". The definition of the word "about" is "on the subject of; concerning" therefore, Big-O is "on the subject of time". I can say that "Calculus is about numbers" and I'm not trying to say the definition, I'm trying to say the topic that it deals with.

Comment: @4castle I've said my say.  I recommend you follow up on the readings I suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129073/discussion-between-4castle-and-pjs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your very first problem is here:

```
 else return 0;
```

At some point; your recursion ends; and reaches that if.

And then you start multiplying the result of that last call ... and guess what x * y * z * ... * 0 might compute to?!

So all your method is doing is returning some m * n value (where n is your input; and m depends on how often you recursively call your own method. As your code translates to:

```
  if (n>eps) {
    return n + findValueOfTheFunction(n/2)
```

Long story short: your computation looses the "interesting" part of its result. So - instead of returning 0 ... return 1!

Comment: In that case, in what condition should I stop the recursion?

Comment: See my updated answer: the point is that you should not return a value that "discards" recursive **multiplication**! And for the record: I am not confirming that your assumption about n*log(n) is true/false. All I am saying is: your **code** does not match the required function T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to write code for this? You can do some math by giving values to n and then substitution:

```
t(1) = 2t(1/2) + 1
t(2) = 2t(1) + 1 = 2(2t(1/2)+1) = 2*2t(1/2)
t(4) = 2t(2) + 1 = 2*2*2*t(1/2)
t(8) = 2t(4) + 1 = 2*2*2*2*t(1/2)
```

The remaining 2*1 is not so important, you can keep staying with t(1/2) part. I guess already something is coming up.